# How can I select all subnodes of a node, and not all descendats?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I've got the following XML:

```
<...>
  <...>
    <tabular>
        <time from="2014-05-22T10:00:00" to="2014-05-22T12:00:00" period="1">
          <symbol number="3" numberEx="3" var="03d" />
          <precipitation value="0" />
          <windDirection deg="191.8" code="SSW" />
          <windSpeed mps="1.3" />
          <temperature unit="celsius" value="16" />
          <pressure unit="hPa" value="1010.6" />
        </time>
        <time from="2014-05-22T10:00:00" to="2014-05-22T12:00:00" period="1">
          <symbol number="3" numberEx="3" var="03d" />
          <precipitation value="0" />
          <windDirection deg="191.8" code="SSW" />
          <windSpeed mps="1.3" />
          <temperature unit="celsius" value="16" />
          <pressure unit="hPa" value="1010.6" />
        </time>
        <time from="2014-05-22T10:00:00" to="2014-05-22T12:00:00" period="1">
          <symbol number="3" numberEx="3" var="03d" />
          <precipitation value="0" />
          <windDirection deg="191.8" code="SSW" />
          <windSpeed mps="1.3" />
          <temperature unit="celsius" value="16" />
          <pressure unit="hPa" value="1010.6" />
        </time>
```

I've managed with LINQ to get the tabular list:

```
var tabular = doc.Root.Descendants("tabular").ToList();
```

tabular count is now 1. What I want is a list of children of tabular. I've tried the extra descendant:

```
var tabular = doc.Root.Descendants("tabular").Descendants().ToList();
```

But that return a list of every descendant of tabular, resulting in a list where time, symbol, precipitation and so on is in the list. How can I get a list where the list contains time nodes of tabular?

I want a list of all time nodes, so I can serialize it to a object and access the values

Answer (score 4):

Use `Elements` instead of `Descendants` if you want to get only direct children of `tabular`

```
var tabular = doc.Root.Descendants("tabular").Elements().ToList();
```

UPDATE: Hints for parsing time elements into objects

```
var times =
    from t in xdoc.Descendants("tabular").Elements()
    let symbol = t.Element("symbol")
    let temperature = t.Element("temperature")
    select new
    {
        From = (DateTime)t.Attribute("from"),
        To = (DateTime)t.Attribute("to"),
        Period = (int)t.Attribute("period"),
        Symbol = new
        {
            Number = (int)symbol.Attribute("number"),
            NumberEx = (int)symbol.Attribute("numberEx"),
            Var = (string)symbol.Attribute("var")
        },
        Precipitation = (int)t.Element("precipitation").Attribute("value"),
        WindSpeed = (double)t.Element("windSpeed").Attribute("mps"),
        Temperature = new
        {
            Unit = (string)temperature.Attribute("unit"),
            Value = (string)temperature.Attribute("value")
        }
    };
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    From: "2014-05-22T10:00:00",
    To: "2014-05-22T12:00:00",
    Period: 1,
    Symbol: { Number: 3, NumberEx: 3, Var: "03d" },
    Precipitation: 0,
    WindSpeed: 1.3,
    Temperature: { Unit: "celsius", Value: "16" }
  },
  // ...
]
```

Comment: Wow... that was easy. Missed that function. To serialize this, I have to create a object that has the same objects/properties of the <time> element?

Comment: @Jason94 sorry, didn't get serialization question. Maybe you are asking about deserialization of this xml? Or you want to parse time elements into some object?

Comment: I want to parse each of the time elements to a object :) (thats part two, part one was getting the proper elements)

Comment: @Jason94 well, frankly speaking that's a completely different question. But I'll update answer with a little hint on further parsing. I'll use anonymous objects, but you can create appropriate classes for time instances

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yep, so my initial question was answered! thank you. Got 3 mins left before I can accept it :)